# Snow Leopard + cucumber/webrat/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rspec, cucumber

Since I've upgraded to snow leopard I've been having tons of problems using cucumber to run my features.

Currently, every time I run cucumber I get the following error.

> Missing these required gems: webrat
>   cucumber  >= 0.3.100   webrat  >=
>   0.5.0   rspec  >= 1.2.6   rspec-rails  >= 1.2.6
>
> You're running: ruby 1.9.1.243 at
>   /usr/local/bin/ruby rubygems 1.3.5 at
>   /Users/nkassis/.gem/ruby/1.9.1,
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>
> Run `rake gems:install` to install the
>   missing gems.

All these gems are installed (and reinstalled after snow leopard upgrade).

Comment: Your title sounds like some kind of horrible third-world meal.

Comment: Hehe, I did that to catch people's attention, seems to have worked ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many Ruby installations do you have going on?  I notice you have a custom Ruby 1.9 installation.  My bet is that your gem path is confused, or that you're running a different Ruby than you think you are in different contexts.

Run both `which ruby` and `which gem` and make sure they're both coming from the same place.  Then try running `gem env` and confirm that the directories it gives for your gem path are the ones where your gems are installed.  If you're using Passenger, confirm that the config files in your Apache setup contain the right Ruby path, and then check whatever programs you use to invoke your tests (rake, autotest, whatever) and make sure they're running the same Ruby.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that the cucumber binary I was using was the wrong one. My $PATH was a mess.